# PHP: Dynamically copying the contents of an array?

Tags: php

I have two arrays, and a function.

```
private $configuration;
private $parameters;

private function setParameters() {
    // 
}
```

Inside the `setParameters` function, I want to assign elements to the `parameters` array. Both of these variables are arrays, and I need to copy the contents from `configuration` to `parameters`.

Configuration array works a little different, inside the `configuration` are nested arrays, the array `configuration` merely contains file names, inside that are nested arrays, similar to Laravel's config.

So, here is an example of how my `configuration` structure may look, sorry if you notice any mistakes, I hand wrote this without a text editor or IDE.

These arrays may go much further in terms of nesting, I just kept it simple here for readability.

```
[   
    "config_file_1" => [
        [
            "name" => "Example",
            "author" => "John"
        ]
    ],

    "config_file_2" => [
        [
            "country" => "Japan",
            "city" => "Tokyo"
        ]
    ],
]
```

This would need to be the equifalent to the code below.

```
$this->parameters["config_file_1.name"] = "Example";
$this->parameters["config_file_1.author"] = "John";
$this->parameters["config_file_2.country"] = "Japan"; // ETC, ETC...
```

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to ask and what errors you are facing...

Comment: I'm not facing an error, I'm asking how I can do this. I am stuck on how I can do this, I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want to achieve with the whole thing... but if I understand you correctly you don't need the parameters array in a good code... you could build something like `$this->config_file[1]->name` and so on...

Comment: I'm unsure, how is the question not simple enough for you to understand, is there a way I can simplify it? It seems self explanatory to me.

Comment: What's the point of having another array with same values?

Comment: @u_mulder because the second array is structured a lot differently, and used for something that needs it to be set out like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
              $configuration = [
        'config_file_1'=> [
            "name" => "Example",
            "author" => ['John', 'Do', 'Ou']],
        'config_file_2' => [
            "country" => "Japan",
            "city" => ["1", '2', '3'],
            'val' => ['a'=>'x', 'b'=> 'y']]
    ];

        $parameters = [];

    foreach($configuration  as $con => $config){
        foreach($config as $key => $value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                foreach($value as $keys => $value){
                    $parameters["{$con}.{$key}.{$keys}"] = $value;
            }} else {
                $parameters["{$con}.{$key}"] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

        print_r($parameters);
//        Array
//        (
//            [config_file_1_name] => Example
//            [config_file_1_author] => John
//            [config_file_2_country] => Japan
//            [config_file_2_city] => Tokyo
//        )
```

Comment: This is what I was after, except it only goes one level deep, if for example `country` was another array (a nested array, inside a nested array) it would return an array object, and not the string conversion.

If I try going a level deeper with another array, it will throw a `Array to string conversion` error.